# Expandable Table AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here's my code:

```
<tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat-start="person in people">
        <td>
          <button ng-if="person.expanded" ng-click="person.expanded = false">-</button>
          <button ng-if="!person.expanded" ng-click="person.expanded = true">+</button>
        </td>

        <td>{{person.name}}</td>
        <td>{{person.gender}}</td>
        <td>
          <button ng-if="person.expanding" ng-click="person.expanding = false">-</button>
          <button ng-if="!person.expanding" ng-click="person.expanding = true">+</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-if="person.expanded" ng-repeat-end="">
        <td colspan="3">{{person.details}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-if="person.expanding" ng-repeat-end="">
        <td colspan="3">{{person.gender}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

First function `ng-if="person.expanded" ng-click="person.expanded = false"` works, but second not. Is it through multiple ng-repeat-end?
Plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/g1t4pludTTIAJYKTToCK?p=preview
 `+` on left side works, on right not.
Thanks for answers in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have to put only one ng-repeat-end at the last tr element

updated code :

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat-start="person in people">
    <td>
      <button ng-if="person.expanded" ng-click="person.expanded = false">-</button>
      <button ng-if="!person.expanded" ng-click="person.expanded = true">+</button>
    </td>

    <td>{{person.name}}</td>
    <td>{{person.gender}}</td>
    <td>
      <button ng-if="person.expanding" ng-click="person.expanding = false">-</button>
      <button ng-if="!person.expanding" ng-click="person.expanding = true">+</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-if="person.expanded">
    <td colspan="3">{{person.details}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-if="person.expanding" ng-repeat-end="">
    <td colspan="3">{{person.gender}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```